# PHP post_max_size won't set

Tags: php

searched through any Thread but couldn't find a solution.

I want a `post_max_size` as large as 20MB for `Zurmo`

I'm running a `Centos 6.5` Server with `Plesk12`.

I edited the php.ini to the following.

```
memory_limit = 256M

file_uploads = On

upload_max_filesize = 20M

post_max_size = 20M
```

But still `Zurmo` is saying

```
PHP post_max_size setting is: 8M minimum requirement is: 20M
```

When I go into the php.ini the value is set on 20M.

I restarted the Apache several times, even rebootet the Server, and now I'm stuck.

EDIT://
I also created a info.php to see if it see another Value, but it still sees the 8M instead of 20
//

Anyone has an idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it's the correct PHP ini file? What does `phpinfo()` print out in terms of the ini file it uses?

Comment: You Sir have helped me... I answered my Question thank you soo much!

Comment: I realized another PHP.ini overwrote the base php.ini

Thanks very much for enlightening me!